# Convert img tag to SVG without AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, svg

I found (and customized) a snippet a while back that allows for converting `<img>` tags of SVG files into actual `<svg>` elements. This has been working great, but I'm thinking it could be more optimized.

```
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var oThis = jQuery(this); //Store it so it can be easily referenced inside of the AJAX function

    if ( oThis.attr('src').indexOf('.svg') >= 1 ){ //If it is actually an SVG image
        jQuery.get(oThis.attr('src'), function(data){ //AJAX begins...
            var theSVG = jQuery(data).find('svg'); //Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            theSVG = theSVG.attr('id', oThis.attr('id')); //Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            theSVG = theSVG.attr('class', oThis.attr('class') + ' replaced-svg'); //Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            theSVG = theSVG.attr('data-original-src', oThis.attr('src')); //Add an attribute of the original SVG location
            theSVG = theSVG.removeAttr('xmlns:a'); //Remove invalid XML tags
            oThis.replaceWith(theSVG); //Replace image with new SVG
        }, 'xml');
    }
});
```

Basically what that is doing is simply getting the `src` of the `<img>` tag and AJAXing to retrieve the file itself, then replacing the element with the actual `<svg>` code itself.

There is a FOUC on pageload when this happens (because sometimes I stylize the SVG with CSS, so it will show the unstyled `<img>` tag first on load while the AJAX is still happening.

To combat this, and to reduce requests in general, I thought I'd try to optimize this.

**Is there a way to pull the SVG file itself that has already been requested on pageload by the browser instead of having to AJAX to request the exact same file?**

Comment: What does your network tab say about how the image was loaded?  It should say (at least in chrome) "loaded from disk cache". The loading of the image via the ajax request should be entirely negligible.  Otherwise, you could wrap the markup that includes the image in a `<template>` tag in the loaded HTML to prevent rendering while you fetch the source using the ajax request. You won't see the image until you replace the template with the SVG on browsers that support `<template>`. Otherwise, you could look into javascript image preloaders. In any case, the load time should be negligible already.

Comment: Ok, I can see what you're saying. I was using the Network tab but the resource was showing up under both SVG and XHR, and I didn't realize that it was the being loaded immediately from the AJAX, so the time is negligible like you described. I bet the FOUC is simply the time before DOM ready which is when the AJAX is triggered, so I can look into optimizing there. Thanks.